# Node js file upload to s3 or local

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, formidable

I want to create a file upload service for node backend

The files can be uploaded to amazon s3 bucket or local server depending on the configuration.

As far as I understood

I can use s3-upload stream to upload to s3 bucket. I have the following question

1. In the example on npm mpdule page

   var read = fs.createReadStream('./path/to/file.ext');

The stream is created using local file. How can I read input stream from client and pipe it to s3. Can I use formidable for this ?

The file size can be very large. The upload service should be production ready serving multiple requests.
Point to any documentation or guide for my use case will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If want to stick with s3-upload-stream, I suggest you to use Busboy:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy

```
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  // Instead of the events 'data' and 'end' as the show in the documentation
  // you can just pipe the file to the upload from s3-upload-stream

  file.pipe(upload);
});
```

I grab these piece of code from the link above. The file you get from busboy is your readable stream.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS JavaScript SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) for [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html). There are some [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html) of using Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is node.js SDK for AWS available out there that already has methods to upload to S3.
http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/